# Failed to install zbar in wndows for python using pip install zbar

Tags: python

Collecting zbar
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/33/54/cc5819efc9ee7e34b60b41e1d2d4753b6dd0c26a41c9a552611f66aa106e/zbar-0.10.tar.bz2

Installing collected packages: zbar
  Running setup.py install for zbar ... error

> Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import
>   setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='c:\users\k\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-y0jgcd\zbar\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record c:\users\k\appdata\local\temp\pip-labpqj-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
>       running install
>       running build
>       running build_ext
>       building 'zbar' extension
>       error: INCLUDE environment variable is empty
>
> Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='c:\users\k\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-y0jgcd\zbar\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record c:\users\k\appdata\local\temp\pip-labpqj-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\k\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-y0jgcd\zbar\

how to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try the install steps provided in : https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar/blob/master/README